# Вопрос по задаче kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Что делать с выводом, в данной задаче?
Мой вариант решения:

```
  class Navigator {
        fun getDestination(path: Array<Direction>): String {
            var x = 0
            var y = 0
            for (i in path) {
                when (i) {
                    Direction.UP -> println("(x: $x, y: ${y++})")
                    Direction.DOWN -> println("(x: $x, y: ${y--})")
                    Direction.RIGHT -> println("(x: ${x++}, y: $y)")
                    Direction.LEFT -> println("(x: ${x--}, y: $y)")
                    return Direction
                }
            }        
        }
    }
```

Задача:

Василий Иванович устроился на работу водителем. Сегодня ему поручили отвезти очередного пассажира, уточнив, что точного адреса пассажир, к сожалению, не знает, но он помнит дорогу и будет указывать водителю направление.

Изначально Василий Иванович находится в точке x:0, y:0. Ваша задача - разработать программу, которая рассчитает, в какой точке окажется Василий Иванович в конце поездки.

Описано перечисление Direction:

```
enum class Direction {
    UP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT
}
```

Каждый элемент этого перечисления - это направление, в котором может двигаться водитель.

UP - перемещение на +1 по оси y
RIGHT - перемещение на +1 по оси x
DOWN - перемещение на -1 по оси y
LEFT - перемещение на -1 по оси x
Опишите класс Navigator, имеющий единственный метод со следующей сигнатурой:

```
fun getDestination(path: Array<Direction>): String {

}
```

Эта функция должна, используя массив path, определить, куда попал водитель. Функция должна вернуть строку в следующем формате:

(x: X, y: Y)
Где X и Y - координаты водителя в конце поездки

Вот пример работы данной функции:

```
val navigator = Navigator()

val destination = navigator.getDestination(arrayOf(Direction.UP, Direction.LEFT, Direction.LEFT))

// destination = (x: -2, y: 1)
```

Здесь водитель переместился один раз вверх (UP, + по оси y) и два раза влево (LEFT, - по оси x).

Печатать в консоль ничего не нужно.

Comment: Исправьте возврат значения из функции в нужном формате и готово. Класс Navigator по сути бесполезен, используется как обертка для функции, в Котлине можно и без нее. Но это уже детали.

Comment: А как именно, не подскажите?

Comment: return "(x: $x, y: $y)" и после цикла, а не внутри, как у вас сейчас. Учите основы.

Comment: Compilation error
main.kt:43:40: error: expecting '->'
                return "(x: x, y: x,y:y)"
                                                       ^

Comment: Не могу понять, где он ожидает стрелку?

Comment: А, всё, разобрался. Спасибо большое!